# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).apeend is not a function

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I have this script:

```
$("<tr>").appendTo($ul)
         .apeend($("<td>").text(item.id).appendTo($ul))
         .apeend($("<td>").text(item.fname).appendTo($ul))
         .apeend($("<td>").text(item.lname).appendTo($ul));
});
```

And the console shows below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).apeend is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (test2.jsp:23)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (test2.jsp:21)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You have a typo. `append` not `apeend`

Comment: it's not `apeend` . it need to be `append`. check and correct

Comment: oki , i don't noticed it i have fixed it thanks :)

Comment: You should also remove those `.appendTo($ul)` that you do for every `td`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>    
<body>
    <button id="but">click me </button>
    <div id="test">
<table id="name"></table>
    </div>
        </body>

</html>
```

in jquery

```
$('#name').dataTable().fnClearTable();
$('#name').dataTable().fnDraw();
$('#name').dataTable().fnDestroy();
$.ajax({

    type : "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : 'Your URL',
    data : JSON.stringify(),
    success : function(result) 
    {

        if (result != "") 
        {
            edit_count=0;
            row_count = 0;
            $.each(result,function(i,item) {
                    row_count++;
                    edit_count++;

                                tr = $('<tr/>');
                                tr
                                        .append("<td style='text-align:left;padding-left:20px;'>"
                                                + item[0]
                                                + "</td>");
                                tr
                                        .append("<td style='text-align:left;padding-left:20px;'>"
                                                + item[1]
                                                + "</td>");
                                tr
                                        .append("<td style='text-align:left;padding-left:20px;'>"
                                                + item[2]
                                                 +"</td>");




                                $('#name').append(tr);


            });


            }
        }
    });
```